# Visual Studio Code Call Hierarchy

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently saw a video that showed a nice call hierarchy feature available for VS Code (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5LA7ivUb2c). However, when trying this in my own VS Code editor by right clicking on a function, the "Show Call Hierarchy" option is not visible.

I have the latest version of VS Code installed so am quite surprised that this feature is not available. Since I mainly code in C++ (and sometimes C), and use Linux (Ubuntu) as my OS, could these be possible reasons why the call hierarchy feature is not available for my editor?

Comment: It is a relatively new feature.  Is there a C++ extension that supports call hierarchy?  Typescript/javascript support is baked in at this point (hence your video) but other languages have to provide that data themselves.

Comment: `VS Code has built-in call hierarchy support for **JavaScript/TypeScript** and extensions can add support for other languages such as Python and Java` from the description.

Comment: It does :) Just mention the docs..

Answer (score 0):

As of today, `vscode-cpptools` does not support this: see this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/16).
As you can see, we are not the only ones desperately needing that feature.

As suggested there, you can try and install [vscode-clangd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd) (make sure to disable the C/C++ extension, it should prompt to do that once installed anyways).
Once you have configured it via `compile_commands.json`, you get pretty much everything out of the box, including call hierarchy.
This has still some limitations, see [this issue](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd/issues/299), that, unfortunately, is out of the developers' control.

Bottom line: if you can live with this, use `vscode-clangd` and let's pray someone will hear our suggestions, or consider using another IDE, for instance Visual Studio.

For those interested in cross-compilatation with C++, here is a [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82328/c-cross-compilation-and-wsl2-which-ide-should-i-use) I asked a few days ago. To this day, still unanswered and uncommented, but might worth checking out every once in a while.

That being said, I think it is pretty sad that in 2022 it is so difficult to find an IDE worth the name for C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

'Show Call Hierachy' is now available in C++ Extension in VS Code version 1.16 !!!
Just right-click on your function name and select 'Show Call Hierachy'